# Python and CloudFlare issue

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, cloudflare

I hit the wall trying to make request to *https://1stkissmanga.io/* due to CloudFlare protection. I prepared header and cookie (which i read from Firefox) but still without success. What is weird, i can get this site properly with wget. This is the problem i don't understand - wget doesn't have any CloudFlare bypass mechanisms so if it works from wget then shouldn't it work also from Python requests?
Of course with wget i still need to give cookie value, otherwise wget will hit CloudFlare as well.
With wget (successful result):

`wget "https://1stkissmanga.io/" -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" --header="Cookie: __cf_bm=<some long string with dots and other special characters>"`

With python:

`headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",} cookies = {"__cf_bm": "<some long string with dots and other special characters>",}`

`url = "https://1stkissmanga.io/" res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)`

I tried also to put cookie into header like

`headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0", "cookie": "__cf_bm=<some long string with dots and other special characters>",}`

and do `res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` but the result is the same. Whatever i do, request always stop on CloudFlare protection.

Not sure what to do next, CloudFlare proxy is out of question for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use string inside "Cookie" key, not dict. It should look like this `{"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0", "Cookie": "cf_clearance=<some hash here>; cf_chl_2=<some hash here>; cf_chl_prog=x11; XSRF-TOKEN=<some hash here>; laravel_session=<some hash here>; __cf_bm=<some hash here>;"}`

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see a differences beetween this, and beetween one of my tries. Are You trying to say that what i put into headers object is dict, not string? I didn't invented that, i just looked for examples how others do it and put it in my code. If You could wide the context, or just put the line of real coded part how should i put header into request.

Answer (score 0):

The comlete code looks like this, but remember that check works for 10-15 minutes, after that you will need to take new cookie from browser.

```
import requests
h = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0", 
"Cookie": "cf_clearance=<some hash here>; cf_chl_2=<some hash here>; cf_chl_prog=x11; XSRF-TOKEN=<some hash here>; laravel_session=<some hash here>; __cf_bm=<some hash here>;"
}
requests.get(url, headers=h)
```

Comment: In the response for original request, site returns the new cookie code which i can also put for next request. I tried it with the python and it still doesn't work. I have read somewhere that CloudFlare can recognize python script somehow and the detection is related to SSL fingerprint. Due to 100% failure rate of my tries i had put it aside for now and went back to other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the casing of the headers. Headers are supposed to be case insensitive but cloudflare expects the casing to be consistent with the browser being used. I've found success in forcing the client to use HTTP 1.1 as wget does and use title-cased headers as FF does.

This doesn't work:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
cookie: __cf_bm=????
accept: */*
accept-encoding: identity
connection: Keep-Alive
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/119.0
host: ????
```

This works:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Cookie: __cf_bm=????
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/119.0
Host: ????
```